# Rails - can't connect form to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

I need to make a form that sends two hidden fields to a controller.  The form is not bound to any specific object, I just need to get the inputs to the controller.  Here is my view code:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "projects", action: "change_state_from_posting_to_actual_job") do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field_tag :relationship_id, value: relationship.id  %></div>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field_tag :project_id, value: project.id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "Apply", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I am receiving the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"change_state_from_posting_to_actual_job", :controller=>"projects"}
```

But i definitely have a controller and action with those names (The controller is actually projects_controller, but I've tried that.  Ive also tried ProjectsController).

Here is my route:

```
get 'change_state', to: 'projects#change_state_from_posting_to_actual_job', as: :change_state
```

How do I get the form to go to the controller?

Comment: Do you have a route in your `config/routes.rb` that maps to that action?

Comment: yes, I will post the route now

Comment: then why don't you just use `change_state_path` in your `form_tag`?

Comment: And, btw, you don't really need the form-builder object `f`, 'cause you don't have an actual object associated with the form. So I'd prefer to remove that.

Comment: I tried that, but then i get the error:  'No route matches [POST] "/projects/show_applicants"'.

Comment: I might be missing a point here. You're renaming your routes and actions so fast that I can't really follow.

Comment: I didn't rename it.  show_appliccants is the page the form is on.  I'm not sure why it's bringing that up when i submit the form?

Comment: Almaron, for some reason when i do form_for change_state_path, i get the error: 'No route matches [POST] "/projects/show_applicants"'

Answer (score 0):

Your route is simply `/change_state`. Remove `controller` and just specify the route.

```
form_tag('/change_state') do |f|
```

---

You're missing the `id` component of your route (assuming `change_state` operates on a specific project).

Either use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`...

```
form_for [project, :change_state] do |f|
```

or  supply the `id` component of your `form_tag` URL options:

```
form_tag(id: project.id, controller: 'projects', action: 'change_state') do |f|
```

Comment: I can't make it a form for project because ichange_state doesn't operate on a specific project.

Comment: Then there's a few problem with your routes, both technical and logical. Technical: Rails doesn't think you've defined the route; show us your routes (edit the relevant ones into your question) and logical: Why are you passing a hidden `project_id` to a method in the projects controller, if that method doesn't operate on a specific project? Your form is clearly doing something to a *specific* project, so, why isn't the route wired up to support that?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you are saying.  This form is for the part of an internship site where an employer can accept an applicant.  I need this controller to change two things, the 'state' column in a 'projects' table and a 'state' column in a 'relationships' table.  I tried your suggestions.  The second suggestion returned the error: 'syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
...t_buffer.append=  form_tag (id: project.id, controller: 'pro...'  .  The first suggestion returned the error: 'undefined method `project_change_state_from_posting_to_actual_job_path''

Comment: I think you're right, it probably should target the specific project.  For some reason, I can't get that to work.  The form is inside of an each loop iterating through @projects.  the loop says '@projects.each do |project|' but for some reason when i make a 'form_for project', it says undefined method, even though i know project is defined because it is going through the loop.

Comment: When I do 'form_for [project, :change_state_from_posting_to_actual_job]' I get the error: 'undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class'